# How can we remove undeclared function error when function is declared with typedef in c?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, typedef

When i have run the following piece of code:

```
typedef char *lrfield();

struct lrfields {
char name[26];
lrfield *f;
};

struct lrfields lr_table[] = {
    {"pri_tran_code1", pri_tran_code2},
    {"sec_tran_code", sec_tran_code},
    {"type_code", type_code},
    {"sys_seq_nbr", sys_seq_nbr},
    {"authorizer", authorizer},
    {"void_code", void_code},
    {"",0}
};

char *pri_tran_code2()
{
    return pri_tran_code;
}

*
*

if(second) 
{
     for(bp=lr_table; bp->name[0]; bp++)
     if(strcmp(bp->name, second)==0)
     {
         tmpval=bp->f();
         break;
     }
}
```

I have got these errors:

```
error: `pri_tran_code2' undeclared here (not in a function)
error: initializer element is not constant
error: (near initialization for `lr_table[0].f')
error: initializer element is not constant
error: (near initialization for `lr_table[0]')
error: initializer element is not constant
error: (near initialization for `lr_table[1]')
```

As you can see in the code that i have defined 'pri_tran_code2' above its call. Please help me to solve this error.

Comment: The problem is when your compiler reaches the first mention of `pri_tran_code2` the function is really not declared *yet*. You have to prototype the function before declaring your `lr_table[]` array. Also fix your typedef as mentionned by H2CO3

Comment: After declaring the functions before they are referred to, as per Michael Krelin's answer, you'll still face the "error: initializer element is not constant" problem. You can only use `pri_tran_code2` etc., which are not constant expressions, to initialise struct members in function scope, not at file scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `char *pri_tran_code2();` before you mention this name? Or simply move the whole implementation there. It doesn't matter where you *call* it, what matters is where you refer to it.

Comment: Thanks, it works. i have declared the function at wrong place.

Answer (score 3):

Your declaration is erroneous. To declare a function (function-pointer) type, try this instead:

```
typedef char *(*lrfield)();
```

Comment: But the error is not about the declaration, but about the lack of declaration for `pri_tran_code2`?

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker well - nevertheless, the typedef is wrong. And without a typedef, variables/fields/functions of that type cannot be declared. So this may actually help. :)

Comment: I can never remember the syntax, but doesn't the original typedef define the type for the function and `lrfield *` is a pointer? For what I can tell by the lack of compiler's complaints about it, it works?

(and no, it's not likely to help with function being used before being declared, anyway:))

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker last statement: true. Every other: not so true :)

Comment: ;-), I have to either agree or check myself and I prefer the former at the moment ;-)

Comment: Hmm, I can use `typedef char *lrfield();` with a `char *foo(void);` per `lrfield *bar = &foo;` without problems. Compiles cleanly with `-std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic` and works as intended.

Comment: @MKSingh Okay. Then, please provide some more context. Thanks! (Also, tried Michael Krelin's solution?)

Comment: I'd recommend applying both solutions and then being more specific about the `doesn't work` part.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin- I have declared 'pri_tran_code2' function using typedef, according to you how can we declare it? does not work means i got same error

Comment: @MKSingh, did I say "using typedef"?!

Comment: @MKSingh, let me repeat it again — either add `char *pri_tran_code2();` before the array or move the whole function there.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker Peeps do not believe you today :D

Comment: MichaelKrelin- i have put a line 'lrfield pri_tran_code2;' after typedef statement and i got these new errors:                          error: conflicting types for 'lrfield'
error: previous declaration of 'lrfield' was here

Comment: @MKSingh your compiler says that `lrfield` is a variable, declared twice with conflicting types. How does your code look now?

Comment: @DanielFischer-i have add these lines:typedef char *lrfield();
lrfield pri_tran_code2; rest are same i had mentioned in the code

Comment: @MKSingh Works here (gcc-4.5.1). What compiler are you using?

Comment: @MichaelKrelin- Thanks, it works. i have declared the function at wrong place.